# How to get the playbutton / pause back to work

Tags: javascript, html

**Hello guys!**

Currently working on my website. but suddenly there is a line of code not working probaly.
I need my playbutton work so when on click that it change to pause icon instead of play.
but on codepen it works but suddenly not on my site. so what could be wrong?

Thanks,

(**html:**)

```js
// function with addEventListener
const el = document.querySelector('.fa-solid fa-solid1 fa-2x fa-circle-play');
 
el.addEventListener('click', changeClass, true);

function changeClass()
{
    if (el.classList.contains('fa-circle-play') == true) {
               el.classList.remove('fa-circle-play')
        el.classList.add('fa-circle-pause')
    } else {
               el.classList.remove('fa-circle-pause')
      el.classList.add('fa-circle-play')
        
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="playercontent">
    <div class="playercenter">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-solid1 fa-2x fa-volume-high" class="audio-player-volume-button" data-volume="up"></i>
      &nbsp;
      <i class="fa-solid fa-solid1 fa-2x fa-circle-play " onclick="togglePlay()"></i>
```

Comment: PS: `if (el.classList.contains('fa-circle-play') == true) {` just use `if (el.classList.contains('fa-circle-play')) {` since it already returns a boolean. Also there's no need to toggle two classes. You need a default style, and toggle just one class, and that can be done in a single line of JS instead of 7, and that's `el.classList.toggle("fa-circle-play", !elMedia.paused);`

Comment: First of, avoid HTML inline `on*` handlers. Always use `Element.addEventListener()` instead. Secondly make sure you defer the initialization of scripts `<script defer src="">`, or rather place all the `<script>` tags right before the closing body tag. Now the scripts being down below, the interpreter cannot reason about a function called `togglePlay` inside an earlier appearance when using `onclick` attribute - hence my first suggestion. Use JS from one place only and that's the respective tag or file. Not HTML inline.

Comment: Check the browser's console for error messages; there are likely to be some there

Answer (score 1):

If the codepen works, then you've copied it badly and changed it as well. The very first line is bad syntax and even if it was correct in syntax, it still wouldn't work:

```
const el = document.querySelector('.fa-solid fa-solid1 fa-2x fa-circle-play');
```

If you actually tried to debug this code, this line should return `null` and go no further. In the selector `" fa-solid1 fa-2x fa-circle-play"` is nothing and also invalidates the only properly written class `".fa-solid"` There are other mistakes but they are so simple I feel that showing something correctly would prove a better direction.

***Details are commented in example***

```js
/** 
 * Reference target element with a rarely shared class or an id.
 * Do not reference a class that you plan to add/remove/toggle.
 * So don't use ".fa-circle-play" and ".fa-circle-pause" classes.
 */
const btn = document.querySelector('#play-pause');

/**
 * Register `btn` to the "click" event by an event property as 
 * seen here, or by `.addEventListener()`.
 * This anonymous event handler has an array of two classes:
 * ["fa-circle-play", "fa-circle-pause"].
 * Each className will be toggled on the `btn` which is 
 * referenced as event.target (the element that the user
 * clicked). As long as `btn` started with only one of those 
 * classNames, each click will successfully flip-flop from
 * one className to other className.
 */
btn.onclick = event => {
  ["fa-circle-play", "fa-circle-pause"].forEach(className => {
    event.target.classList.toggle(className);
  });
};
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<i id="play-pause" class="fa-solid fa-2x fa-circle-play"></i>
```

Comment: Allright as first thanks. the script works here in the snippet but on my site not.
Its so weird why its not working on my site but on here it works :/

Comment: Place `<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">` in the `<head>`. Place the JavaScript in a `<script>` place the `<script>` before the `</body>` tag. In the example, HTML is commented as to where the important aspects of the page is placed.

Comment: Also, the JavaScript posted in your question should be removed as well as the icon: `<i class="fa-solid..." onclick="lame()"></i>` with this: `<i id="play-pause" class="fa-solid fa-2x fa-circle-play"></i>`